# Facebook Share and Like button display same count - that's not right

Tags: facebook

How come the `Share` and `Like` button have the same count?
I just implemented the `Like` button today and should only have around 2-3 likes.

You can see my problem here: http://www.norwegianfashion.no/news/ofw-forbids-fur-on-the-catwalk/

The code I use is this:

```
        <div class="share">
          <div class="face_share">
            <a name="fb_share" type="button_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>  
          </div> 
          <div class="face_like">
            <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=130&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:20px;"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="twitter">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="norw_fashion">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions are doing the same thing now:

> Share is still an option, however we merged the external count so that
>   the count represents total
>   interactions with the URL.
>
> Additionally, ‘like’ still gives you the ability to publish an image
>   when a comment is added (through the
>   XFBML version).

[Source](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2010/05/23/has-facebook-just-merged-its-like-and-share-buttons-apparently-so/).

Comment: So when I share a link on facebook and someone clicks `like` (in facebook), the count will go up?

Comment: @Steven: Now that is an interesting question, but what I think is...if the `like` in facebook is for the *news feed* itself then no, it won't count!

Comment: I just checked. Anyone liking a page I shared on Facebook, will increase the share count.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, this was stated in my answer, but what I meant in my comment is if your friend clicks the `like` link under the feed that is saying `Steven likes blah blah blah`, I guess this won't count as a like for the link you shared/liked but for the news feed itself!